# Using iteration in google apps script to optimise a script that is working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a google apps script that does what I want but I sense that it can be made more elegant by using iteration to go through the if loops.Could someone help me with this ?
My script:

```
function hdud() {
    var column = 4; // This is column "D".

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
        sheet.showColumns(column);
    } else {
        sheet.hideColumns(column);
    }
    var column = 5; // This is column "E".

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
        sheet.showColumns(column);
    } else {
        sheet.hideColumns(column);
    }
    var column = 11; // This is column "K".
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
        sheet.showColumns(column);
    } else {
        sheet.hideColumns(column);
    }
    var column = 12; // This is column "L"
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
        sheet.showColumns(column);
    } else {
        sheet.hideColumns(column);
    }
    var column = 18; // This is column "R".
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
        sheet.showColumns(column);
    } else {
        sheet.hideColumns(column);
    }
    var column = 19; // This is column "S".
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
        sheet.showColumns(column);
    } else {
        sheet.hideColumns(column);
    }

}
```

I expect that the use of iteration could possibly make the code more efficient.

Comment: I think you miss putting your code

Comment: @Twilight oops! there was a posting glitch . The system kept on insisting about beautifying the script with proper indentation and all. After several tries the post was successful but mysteriously the script disappeared. But today fortunately the script was accepted in the edit . Very weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a script that evaluates whether a column is hidden, and then performs an action: (if yes, then unhide, if no, then hide). The script is somewhat repetitive and you are looking for something "more efficient".

How about something like this. I don't think that you would necessarily see a big change in performance, but the script is shorter, easier to read, and easier to manage adding/deleting columns. There are many other ways that this could be coded, but this is probably the lowest common denominator and a good basis for developing better skills.

This answer uses a `for` loop. The column numbers are assigned to an array, and the script loops through each array/(column) value.

---

```
function newhdud() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  
  // an array of Columns to test
  var columns = [4,5,11,12,18,19]
  
  // loop through the columns
  for (var i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
    var column = columns[i]
    if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
        sheet.showColumns(column);
    } else {
        sheet.hideColumns(column);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

**TRY:**

Aside from @Tedinoz approach, this is another way that you may do to avoid the repetition of the same code, it will not use any loop but you can put the `column` as a parameter like this:

```
function hdud(column) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(column)) {
    sheet.showColumns(column);
  } else {
    sheet.hideColumns(column);
  }
}
```

Then you can create another function to call it:

```
function callHdud() {
  hdud(4); // Column "D" for example
  hdud(5);
}
```

The code will also be shorter, easy to read and maintain.

Comment: Btw, Another loops you can use  `forEach()` , `while(){}` , and `do{} while()` , just in case you need more suggestions, the same approach with @Tedinoz you just have to convert it to them.

Comment: Brilliant! This appears to be much  more elegant than what I was seeking. Thanks a lot for your helpful response.